# Trouble with forms using Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I am learning Dom manipulation and using forms with vanilla Javascript and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Right now I just want to be able to click submit and have it console.log the string 'Message Sent' and then reset the form. However when I submit it alters the URL to some weird output and does not console log but instead looks like it refreshes the page but the link still remails altered to "http://localhost:53865/?senderName=&senderEmail=&senderMessage=++++++++++++"

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')


//? Form Submit Button
const button = document.createElement('button')
button.setAttribute('type','submit')
button.textContent = 'Submit'
button.setAttribute('onClick','submit()');
form.appendChild(button)

function submit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log('Message Sent!')
    resetForm();
}

function resetForm() {
    nameInput.value = '';
    emailInput.value = '';
    textArea.value= '';
}



document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(form)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
        <script src = './index.js' defer></script>
     
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <form>
                <input id = 'contact-form' 
                    type="text" 
                    name="senderName" 
                    id = "senderName" 
                    value = "" 
                    placeholder = 'Name' 
                    />
                    <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="senderEmail" 
                    id = "senderEmail" 
                    value = "" 
                    placeholder = 'Email' 
                    />
                    <textarea 
                    type="text" 
                    name="senderMessage" 
                    id = "senderMessage" 
                    value = "" 
                    placeholder = 'Message' 
                    />
            </form> 

       
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whenever doing web development, be sure to keep your devtools console open. If you run this with your console open you'll find an error there saying you're trying to use the property `preventDefault` of `undefined`. That's because in `submit` you're accepting a parameter called `evt` and then doing `evt.preventDefault();`, but you're setting up a call to it like this: `button.setAttribute('onClick','submit()');`. Notice there's no argument to `submit` in that, you just have `submit()`. So `submit` is called with no arguments, so `evt` is `undefined`, and the call fails. (Then...

Comment: `<textarea>` elements aren't self-closing and need `</textarea>`

Comment: ... the form gets submitted because nothing prevented form submission.) Don't use `setAttribute` to set up event handlers. Instead, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): `button.addEventListener("click", submit);`. That sets `submit` as an event handler, and so when the event occurs, the browser will pass it an `Event` object. Also, if you don't want your `button` element to submit the form, don't make it `type="submit"` (which is the default anyway, sadly), make it `type="button"`.